# How to open Jsp page targeted in a html file within form action in the same Html page?

Tags: html, jsp

I am little bit new in J2EE programming. I am creating a simple application in Eclipse to generate a chart with user input. For this I have one html page to take the input which target to one jsp page after submission, which creates a chart after rendering. Currently, the jsp page is opening in the new tab. I want as soon as user enters the data in the html page and click on submit, the jsp page must display on the same page just below the html form and the form data should remains same.

Comment: you're talking about asynchronous behaviour then. You can't just make a jsp page dynamically change content without using javascript. So on the jsp page you'll have to make an ajax call that will check when the user submits the form.

Comment: Thanks, But I haven't worked on AJAX can you give a simple code for same. Or can I provide my code here?